# How to solve such a Bernoulli differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ (x^3 + e^y)*y' = 3x^2 $$

The title of this problem says it is a Bernoulli differential equation although it doesn't have a shape that fits the definition. 
I tried to replace the y with things like ln(x) so $$e^y = e^(lnx) = x $$
but I still couldn't bring it to a form that I can find a solution to.

There's a group of people that tried but still wasn't able to solve it so help would be greatly appreciated.

[Image of one of the ways I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnvwK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $3x^2$ is the derivative of $f(x)=x^3$. So you can write the equation as
$$
e^yy'=f'(x)-f(x)y'
$$
The right side has $e^{-y}$ as integrating factor. Thus consider the derivative of $$e^{-y}f(x)=e^{-y}x^3.$$

Comment: $$  y' = e^{(-y)} * f'(x) - e^{(-y)} * f(x) * y' $$

$$ y' = (e^{(-y)} * f(x))' $$

$$ y = e^{(-y)} * f(x) =  e^{(-y)} * x^3 $$

and that solves it right?

Comment: You still need some integration constant. $y+C=e^{-y}x^3$ which can then be transformed to $(y+C)e^{y+C}=e^Cx^3$ and then $y=-C+W(e^Cx^3)$ with one branch of the Lambert-W function.